# Constant network drop between two XP machines

Tags: networking, connection, timeout

I am not sure when this started happening or why, but I have a home office running:

- a "server" XP machine with an external hard drive attached to it via USB, and
- my working machine, also an XP machine.

Lately though, the network connection for the server drops and I cannot figure out what is causing this. I use the Remote Desktop frequently and this too drops off from time to time.

I can ping the server from Fing on my Android device and no packets drop, I can ping the machine from another machine on the network and it does not drop and lose remote desktop connection.

Is there anything else I can check, any monitoring tools I can use to find the source of the problem?

Comment: How are the devices connected? Is it wired is it wireless? If wireless then is there something causing interference? A common occurrence when it drops off line? more details required to help here.

Comment: Hi Joe. All the desktops are Cat5 wired. All the devices are wireless. And it only seems to happen to my machine

Comment: Are they connected via a seperate switch or is it just an all in 1 wireless router / switch they all connect through? Just trying to identify possible points of failiure

Comment: All connected through the one router, a Netgear DGN2000.

Comment: When connection to the server drops can you still connect to other machines on the network from your main pc, to the internet etc? i.e. the problem isn't a complete loss of connection at the client end?

Comment: I still have internet connection and I've not tried remote desktopping into one of the other machines but, it seems only the connection to the server is dropped. Then comes back and drops again for long periods of time. This has happened in the past but nowhere near as bad as this. Are there any constant monitoring tools I could use to see at what point and where it happens?

Comment: I have now narrowed it down to my machine and not the server machine itself. Any other machine on the network can access the server without any problems. If I try and access the content on my machine from any other machine on the network, I get delayed connections, sometimes not connecting at all. So with this narrowed down, what could I look at now? Please.

Comment: Have you checked the physical side of things? Changed ethernet cables, ports etc After that you could look at any software that is running on the client machine, any things that run at the times it drops off. Any torrent software running?

Comment: Hi Joe. I've had to pull out all the power plugs this morning due to heavy thunder which tends to knock out electricals if we don't. I've switched everything on about an hour ago now and thing s are running super smoothly. I am able to connect to the server and also about to remote desktop into it. I will keep an eye on it now as I switch apps on and off to see when it starts happening. Are there any good software tools one could use to monitor something like this; so that at the point it begins I will be able to check the logs or something?

Comment: You could use a network monitoring tool such as wireshark to monitor packets between the machines. once it drops you will know. I've never used it myself though but there is good documentation on the web.

Comment: Thanks Joe! Since I unplugged the machines yesterday, I have not had a single drop or disconnection. Thanks again for all the help everyone.

Comment: So a router reset did the trick? That good old off and on trick, people take the mickey out of us IT Techs for suggetsing that.

Comment: If only it were that simple Joe....the problem is back!!!! aaaargh! It seems though that in the last few days I have started mapping network drives again after I had removed them and now the problem is back. I am going to remove them yet again and see if this is the problem, reboot both machines and monitor the situation. I will report back, but if this perhaps rings a bell with someone, I would appreciate a solution. Thanks!

Comment: I've been running the machines now for a couple of days, not mapping the network drives and so far everything has worked well. Does anyone know if this could be due to the ip addresses being set dynamically? Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't be, the networked drive should use the DNS name doesn't it? Also depending on your usage the machines should retain the same IP addresses even though they are dynamic as there won't be enough competition for leases to force them to change. Plus they will probably log on more frequently than the lease expiration time (depending what it's set to)

Comment: Normally if I reboot my machine, things will run smoothly for a while and then it will be locked up again. I just did that a short while ago and when machine came back up, it was still not connecting to my "server". For some reason, I decided to look at a way to reset the DNS thinking there must be a caching issue if all other machines are working fine. I flushed the DNS, no joy. Then released/renewed the IP address and presto, it worked! I will now continue to monitor this and if I do it again and again, I know I have an conflict of IP addresses somewhere that I need to work out. Many thanks!

Comment: Yip, I have nailed it down to the releasing and renewing the IP address because it takes a couple of minutes and the problem comes back i.e. the network drives cannot be reached. As soon as I release and renew the IP addresses, the problem is solved. Yet, this problem does not occur with any of the other computers/devices in the house. I'm now thinking of assigning static ip addresses ranging from  10.0.0.1 - 10.0.0.100. Is this the better route to go?

Comment: It certainaly makes sense, give it a go. It's easily done and undone so worth a try.

Comment: Thanks Joe for all your input! It's much appreciated. Will give it a go today some time.